# .format Not Working in Input() function

Tags: python, input, format

I am making a rock paper scissors program for Python and I have ran into this issue. If I use .format for a username input, and then try to output it in a input string, it just prints as {0} instead of the actual variable. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
User1Name=raw_input('Enter your username.\n')
User1=input('{0}\n--------\n1. Rock\n2. Paper\n3. Scissors\n4. Random\n5. Exit\n').format(User1Name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` in python2 tries to evaluate the string the user inputs, use `raw_input` as your first statement does.

and then it should be:

```
User1=raw_input('{0}\n--------\n1. Rock\nWHATEVER...\n'.format(User1Name))
```